# XSD assert not recognised

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, xsd-validation

I have an XSD where I want to use an `xs:assert` statement. The issue is I don't know how to make the assert functionality available to me. I am using Visual Studio to write it, and it gets a blue line saying it doesn't support the assert element.

My XSD looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns="http://www.client.co.uk/quote" 
           targetNamespace="http://www.client.co.uk/quote" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

<xs:element name="ProductType" type="ProductCodeType"/>
  <xs:simpleType name="ProductCodeType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Client Product Type</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="L" />
      <xs:enumeration value="C" />
      <xs:enumeration value="H" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="BenefitBasisType">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Client benefit basis type</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:assert test= "if (ProductType = 'L') then $value = 'M' else if (ProductType = 'C') then $value = 'F' else if (ProductType = 'H') $value = 'P'" />
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="M" />
        <xs:enumeration value="F" />
        <xs:enumeration value="P" />
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `xs:assert` requires XSD 1.1, and Microsoft Visual Studio only supports XSD 1.0.  You'll have to use an XML processor that supports XSD 1.1 such as one of the following:

- [Xerces-J with PsychoPath XPath 2.0](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html#faq-2)
- [Saxon EE](http://www.saxonica.com/products/feature-matrix-9-6.xml)
- [Altova](http://www.altova.com/products.html)
- [Liquid XML](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-studio.aspx) also [supports it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1019476/XSD-Support-in-Liquid-XML)

Comment: are there any add ons to visual studio that allow use of 1.1 XSD?

Comment: Some of Altova's products integrate with Visual Studio, I don't know if this is true of their XSD processor.

Comment: @Tobias, consider upvoting [this UserVoice post on XSD 1.1](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3109674-xsd-1-1-support), to urge MS to add this. In addition, Saxon has a .NET version, so you can use that. If you want to validate from within the editor, use oXygen, Stylus Studio, Altova, Eclipse.