# Can XML schema validate against parent attribute values?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am using XML for a geolocation project. This uses attributes to define the location of items. A simple 1-dimensional example for the range 0-9 would be:

```
<Range Start="0" Size="10">Some item</Range>
```

Some items have children. The children must always fit within the range of the parent. In the XML below the child element has the `Start` attribute set to 12. This is outside of the logical range defined by the parent element:

```
<Range Start="0" Size="10">
   <Range Start="12" Size="1">Out of range 0-9</Range>
</Range>
```

Can an XSD schema detect this scenario, or is it impossible to validate against parent attribute values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

Not possible.

### XSD 1.1

Define an assertion on the parent element using `xs:assert` and `every` to ensure that children ranges are within boundaries specified by parent range.

Here's how the assertion would look (focussing on just the key `Range` attributes and structure):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="Range">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Range" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Start" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Size" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
            <xs:assert test="every $r in Range satisfies 
                             $r/@Start >= @Start 
                             and $r/@Start + $r/@Size > @Start + @Size"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you. This was really helpful. One word of warning though: This technique requires XSD 1.1 which is not supported by current Microsoft Visual Studio. It seems more specialist (and costly) validators must be used. See [Link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500445/xsd-assert-not-recognised