# Assertion not supported in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am using an assertion in my XSD. `<xs:assert>` is not supporting in my visual studio.

```
 <xs:assert test="count(event[@type='system']) = 1"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Microsoft's XML tools have hardly progressed in 20 years. If you want to use any of the more recent W3C standards, you need to use third-party tools.

Answer (score 1):

`xs:assert` requires XSD 1.1; it is not supported in XSD 1.0.

### See also

- [XSD assert not recognised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32500445/290085), which lists some products that do support XSD 1.1.
- [Where to place an XSD 1.1 assert?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64582004/290085)